# Faster way of converting a variable length list into a data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a variable length list which looks like this

```
chr [1:249] "1" "29.12" "2" "20.78" "3" "12.09" ...
chr [1:200] "1" "20.45" "3" "10.56" "4" "12.34" ...
chr [1:213] "2" "12.20" "3" "19.93" "5" "23.05" ...
```

The values in odd positions ("1", "3", "4", etc) represent variables having specific meaning while the values in even positions are the values for the variables represented by the number before it. E.g. in the second element of the list, the variable "3" has the value "10.56".

I'm trying to convert this into a data frame with values like "10.56" going into the correct column of the data frame i.e. column "3". This is the code I am using

```
e <- unlist(d[[k]])  ## d is my list. k is the index for a for loop
pos_index <- seq(1, length(e), 2) ## gives positions for the variables
val_index <- seq(2, length(e), 2) ## gives positions for corresponding values
df_index <- as.numeric(e[pos_index])

## Populate a pre-defined data frame at calculated positions
CNNIBN_DF[k, df_index] <- as.numeric(e[val_index])
```

The data frame should look something like this

```
   X1    X2    X3    X4    X5
1  29.12 20.78 12.09 NA    NA
2  20.45 NA    10.56 12.34 NA
3  NA    12.20 19.93 NA    23.05
```

This works but takes a long time. `system.time` for 1000 entities gives this

```
user   system  elapsed 
57.64  0.06    58.14
```

The list itself has 33k entities with each entity having 200+ elements. I have tried the same operation using just `for` loops but both tend to take about the same time.

Is there a faster way to do this? I'm using a win32 machine with 4GB of RAM running Intel Core i3 M350 CPU @ 2.27 GHz.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Akrun, already, posted some of the many probable alternatives; I'll just add a more explicit approach that seems to do as less as possible (using akrun's "lst"):

```
ulst = unlist(lst)
cols = seq(1, length(ulst), 2)
inds = cbind(row = rep(seq_along(lst), lengths(lst) %/% 2), 
             col = as.integer(ulst[cols]))
vals = as.numeric(ulst[-cols])
ans = matrix(, max(inds[, "row"]), max(inds[, "col"]))
ans[inds] = vals
#      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
#[1,] 29.12 20.78 12.09    NA    NA
#[2,] 20.45    NA 10.56 12.34    NA
#[3,]    NA 12.20 19.93    NA 23.05
```

From your goal, it seems that you shouldn't necessarily need a "data.frame", but the "matrix" is easily converted to one. Also, it might be worth to look into if you could manipulate the building/fetching of your data in order to avoid this weird format.

Comment: I didn't see your post as the page didn't update.  I updated with a matrix method, but I guess it is different than your approach.

Comment: I would like to benchmark this approach.  Can you make it more general i.e. `length(lst[[1]])`

Comment: @akrun : I mistakenly assumed that all elements in "lst" would be of the same `length`. I changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, your method is faster.  I think it must be because I used `Map` rather than `unlist`ing the whole list

Comment: @akrun : Probably, the `Map` is your bottleneck; I, originally, had the same thought as yours but I tried to avoid anything "_apply"ingly that could be done "vectorisingly"

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
lst1 <- lapply(lst, function(x) { x<- as.numeric(x)
                    indx <- c(TRUE, FALSE)
                   v1 <- tabulate(x[indx])
                   is.na(v1) <- v1==0
                   v1[!is.na(v1)] <- x[!indx]
                   v1 })

setNames(do.call(rbind.data.frame,lapply(lst1, `length<-`,
                         max(lengths(lst1)))), paste0('X', 1:5))
#     X1    X2    X3    X4    X5
#1 29.12 20.78 12.09    NA    NA
#2 20.45    NA 10.56 12.34    NA
#3    NA 12.20 19.93    NA 23.05
```

Or

```
m1 <- do.call(rbind,Map(function(x,y) cbind(x,matrix(as.numeric(y),
          nrow=length(y)/2, byrow=TRUE)), seq_along(lst), lst))
m2 <- matrix(NA, ncol=max(m1[,2]), nrow=length(lst))
m2[m1[,-3]] <- m1[,3]
```

We can use `sparseMatrix` from `Matrix`

```
 library(Matrix)
 d1 <- setNames(as.data.frame(m1), c('Row', 'Col', 'Value'))
 with(d1, sparseMatrix(Row, Col, x=Value))
  #3 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"

 #[1,] 29.12 20.78 12.09  .     .   
 #[2,] 20.45  .    10.56 12.34  .   
 #[3,]  .    12.20 19.93  .    23.05
```

which can be converted to `matrix` by `as.matrix`.

Or

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
d1 <- unnest(lst, group) 
d2 <- bind_cols(slice(d1, seq(1, n(), by=2)), slice(d1, seq(2, n(), by=2))[2])
colnames(d2)[3] <- 'val'
spread(d2, x, val) %>%
                  select(-group)
#     1     2     3     4     5
#1 29.12 20.78 12.09  <NA>  <NA>
#2 20.45  <NA> 10.56 12.34  <NA>
#3  <NA> 12.20 19.93  <NA> 23.05
```

Or

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
library(reshape2)
dcast(setDT(melt(lst))[, list(indx= value[c(TRUE, FALSE)], 
   value=value[c(FALSE, TRUE)]) ,L1], L1~paste0('X', indx), value.var='value')
#   L1    X1    X2    X3    X4    X5
#1:  1 29.12 20.78 12.09    NA    NA
#2:  2 20.45    NA 10.56 12.34    NA
#3:  3    NA 12.20 19.93    NA 23.05
```

#### Benchmarks

For a 1000 entities list,

```
set.seed(42)
lst <- lapply(1:1000, function(i) {v1 <- sample(50:200)[1L]
                     v2 <- sample(1:200, v1, replace=FALSE)
                     as.character(c(rbind(v2, rnorm(v1))))})

system.time({
  m1 <- do.call(rbind,Map(function(x,y) cbind(x,matrix(as.numeric(y), 
     nrow=length(y)/2, byrow=TRUE)), seq_along(lst), lst))
  m2 <- matrix(NA, ncol=max(m1[,2]), nrow=length(lst))
  m2[m1[,-3]] <- m1[,3]
 })
#  user  system elapsed 
# 0.064   0.004   0.067 


system.time({
  m1 <- do.call(rbind,Map(function(x,y) cbind(x,matrix(as.numeric(y),
          nrow=length(y)/2, byrow=TRUE)), seq_along(lst), lst))
  d1 <- setNames(as.data.frame(m1), c('Row', 'Col', 'Value'))
   with(d1, sparseMatrix(Row, Col, x=Value))
   })
#  user  system elapsed 
# 0.068   0.003   0.070 


system.time({d1 <- unnest(lst, group)
          d2 <-  bind_cols(slice(d1, seq(1, n(), by=2)),
                  slice(d1, seq(2, n(), by=2))[2])
          colnames(d2)[3] <- 'val'
          res <- spread(d2, x, val) %>%
                       select(-group)}) 
 #    user  system elapsed 
 #  0.259   0.002   0.261
```

Using the first method is slightly slower

```
 system.time({
       lst1 <- lapply(lst, function(x) { x<- as.numeric(x)
                indx <- c(TRUE, FALSE)
               v1 <- tabulate(x[indx])
               is.na(v1) <- v1==0
               v1[!is.na(v1)] <- x[!indx]
               v1 })

   setNames(do.call(rbind.data.frame,lapply(lst1, `length<-`,
                     max(lengths(lst1)))), paste0('X', 1:5))
      })

 #  user  system elapsed 
 #1.459   0.004   1.463
```

On a `33000` list

```
set.seed(42)
lst <- lapply(1:33000, function(i) {v1 <- sample(50:200)[1L]
                 v2 <- sample(1:200, v1, replace=FALSE)
                   as.character(c(rbind(v2, rnorm(v1))))})
 system.time({
  m1 <- do.call(rbind,Map(function(x,y) cbind(x,matrix(as.numeric(y), 
     nrow=length(y)/2, byrow=TRUE)), seq_along(lst), lst))
  m2 <- matrix(NA, ncol=max(m1[,2]), nrow=length(lst))
  m2[m1[,-3]] <- m1[,3]
 })
 #  user  system elapsed 
 # 6.160   0.102   6.260
```

@alexis_laz method is faster

```
 system.time({
  ulst = unlist(lst)
  cols = seq(1, length(ulst), 2)
 inds = cbind(row = rep(seq_along(lst), lengths(lst) %/% 2), 
            col = as.integer(ulst[cols]))
 vals = as.numeric(ulst[-cols])
 ans = matrix(, max(inds[, "row"]), max(inds[, "col"]))
  ans[inds] = vals
 })
#  user  system elapsed 
#  2.421   0.041   2.460
```

#### data

```
lst <- list(c('1', '29.12', '2', '20.78', '3', '12.09'), c('1', '20.45',
'3', '10.56', '4', '12.34'), c('2', '12.20', '3', '19.93', '5', '23.05'))
```

Comment: Thanks Akrun!  The options given were really helpful.